# pyQt open dialog error

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt

**Python Version 3 - Qgis 2.14**

1 / what's wrong ?

Lot's of solutions are exposed in differents forum but any work for me.
I need to get path to save documents later and i had this error :

> TypeError: QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(QWidget parent=None, QString
>   caption=QString(), QString directory=QString(), QString
>   filter=QString(), QString selectedFilter=None, QFileDialog.Options
>   options=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'instance'

Here is my code :

```
# set event when user click    
# param - function with object argument
dlg.resBtn.clicked.connect(self.getFolder(dlg.txt_res)) 

# function call by click to open dialog
# param - obj : textEditor object update by directory selection
 def getFolder(self,obj):        
        ddir= QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select directory')
        obj.setText(ddir)
```

2 / what is this error ?

If i give no param to QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory() function, windows to explore is open when code is reading. but i just need to open this windows when user click on push button.

If a close window without select directory, i had this error :

> dlg.resBtn.clicked.connect(self.getFolder(dlg.txt_res))     TypeError:
>   connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not
>   'NoneType'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, this work for me: use lambda function to write little function anywhere.

replace

```
dlg.resBtn.clicked.connect(self.getFolder(dlg.txt_res))
```

by

```
dlg.resBtn.clicked.connect(lambda:self.getFolder(dlg.txt_res))
```

***Documentation here :***

- [pyqt documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qpushbutton_widget.htm)
- [about lambda function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)

Comment: You could also use the [function.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) function which easily allows you to incorporate parameters into a connection (i.e. import using `from functools import partial` and then use `dlg.resBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.getFolder, dlg.txt_res))`).